# i keep getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection in my mean stack app

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

Am having trouble while updating my user details on my database using `mat-dialog` in angular when I press the edit icon the server throws an error saying unhandled promise plus the app fails to render and keeps throwing failed to edit user

**Here is my API**

```
app.patch('/admins/:id', (req, res) => {
      User.updateOne({ _id : req.params.id }, { $set : { firstname: req.body.firstname }}, (err, doc) => {
          if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({message: 'Failed to return the updated Edited User Email'});
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({
              doc: doc,
              message: 'Successfully Edited user email...'

            });
          }
      }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: 'Failed to update User : ' + err
        });
      });
    });
```

**Here is my updateinfo.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UpdateinfoService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,) { }

  updateUser(
    firstname: string,

    ) {

    const updateData = {
    firstname,

    };

    this.http.patch<any>( environment.api_url + 'admins/:id', updateData).subscribe(doc => {
      if (doc.status === true) {
        window.alert("Succesfully Updated");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Here is the error am facing**

```
(node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1135)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
        at User.updateOne.catch.err (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/backend/app.js:184:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1136)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
        at User.updateOne.catch.err (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/backend/app.js:184:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1137)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
        at User.updateOne.catch.err (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/backend/app.js:184:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1138)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
        at User.updateOne.catch.err (/Users/retina/Downloads/Clerance/backend/app.js:184:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:2031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1139)
```

Comment: would you help me bro

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove res.json() code from catch block because in callback function you already handle error so no need to send response twise to user

just change your code as follow

```
app.patch('/admins/:id', (req, res) => {
  User.updateOne({ _id : req.params.id }, { $set : { firstname: req.body.firstname }}, (err, doc) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Failed to return the updated Edited User Email'});
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({
          doc: doc,
          message: 'Successfully Edited user email...'

        });
      }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

From angular service file you have to pass value of id like this

```
this.http.patch<any>( environment.api_url + `admins/${your_id_value}`, updateData).subscribe(doc => {
  if (doc.status === true) {
    window.alert("Succesfully Updated");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks bro but now am getting a new error Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "User"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '":id"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ':id',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: Model { User } }

Comment: thanks bro am now getting another error after trying to update Cast to ObjectId failed for value "jumanne" at path "_id" for model "User"